# VMWare ESXi 4.1 VMXNET Ignoring MTU and Sending Jumbo Frames

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, mtu, jumboframes

On my CentOS 5.6 ESXi 4.1 VMs using VMXNET, it looks like they are attempting to send jumbo frames:

[image]

However, all the interfaces are set to MTU 1500. What is causing this behavior?

**Update:**

1. I would think that regardless of the switch, wouldn't those host honor the MTU on the interface?
2. `esxcfg-vswitch -l` already shows 1500

**Update 2:**

- Changing to e1000 works around this issue it seems.

---

Answer (score 3):

ESX/ESXi's vSwitches are just that, switches, nothing more or less, and can happily handle both jumbo and regular frames. By default ESX/ESXi *itself* won't use jumbo frames (for v4.0-v.4u1 anyway) without the instructions below. So I suspect that your Centos guest itself is trying to use jumbo frames, obviously you can switch them off if you're infrastructure can't/doesn't handle them well but overall I wouldn't worry about it.

To switch on ESX/ESXi jumbo frame support do the following either from an SSH session or via the VMa;

`esxcfg-vswitch -l` (which lists the current vSwitch MTU)

`esxcfg-vswitch -m 9000 vSwitch0` (which sets the MTU at 9000)

then use `esxcfg-vswitch -l` again to check it's set, repeat for other vSwitches if you like.

If you have a cluster I'd be tempted to do these changes with the host in maintenance mode then immediately reboot and check MTU again before putting the host back into the cluster.

Comment: Shouldn't the guest not attempt to exceed its own MTU though?